# User Tracking Mode Missing Animation, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mkmapview, mkusertrackingmode

I have This code here including `userTrackingMode = .follow` and it works great but it just pops onto `Userlocation` instead of animating the map to go to the user location ...which is what i want . Anyone can tell me hot to add that animation making the map change onto the user location by animation and not just pop onto it ( if it makes sense )

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBAction func UserTrackingMode(sender: AnyObject) {

        mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode:animated:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setUserTrackingMode:animated` in order to animate the transition:

```
@IBAction func UserTrackingMode(sender: AnyObject) {

    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated:true)
}
```